# Object Detection and Tracking in Video

Tags: winforms, video

I am capturing video streams. I have a set of image values and I would like to know if any of these values are appear in the captured streams. Anyone can advise me to achieve this? I’m developing a windows application using C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure only using C# it is not possible to derive the solution. You must use some image processing algorithms.

As to code those algorithms will be a huge activity, you can use Image processing libraries available on internet. May be open cv (emgu cv for .net) or Aforge.Net might help you. If you are building any professional software, I would recommend you to check out the license of respective products.